# How to write a Mongo Query for count _id for specfic month and group by year

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Hi how to write a equivalent query to

```
select count(_id), year from table where month="1" group by year
```

I am have a document of data with 10000+ records, what i want is to count _id for month January and group by year in mongo

Mongodb Query i written is

```
    db.collection.aggregate( 
   {$project : { 
          month : {$month : new Date("$displayDate")}, 
          year : {$year :  new Date("$displayDate")}
      }}, 
    {$group : { 
            _id : {month : "$month" ,year : "$year" },  
          count : {$sum : 1} 
    }})
```

Comment: What is the data type of field `displayDate`? I doubt calling `new Date(...)` on a value which might already be a `Date` object.

Comment: it is column date

Comment: Then it should be simply `{$month: "$displayDate"}`

Comment: okay, how to group by year and count(_id) for specific month

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only data from January then the aggregation would be this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( 
 {$project : { 
      month : {$month : "$displayDate"}, 
      year : {$year :  "$displayDate"}
  }}, 
 {$match: {month: 1}},
 {$group : { 
        _id : {year : "$year" },  
      count : {$sum : 1} 
 }})
```

Note, `Date` values in MongoDB are always UTC times, you may get a time shift. You may prefer [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/index.html) in order to specify the time zone.

Comment: Then add `{ $unset: "_id" }` at the end. Most likely you are looking for `{$project: {year: "$_id.year", count: 1}}`